# Playing sound in animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, mediaelement

I'm having an issue with playing a sound in animation when the animation is run multiple times (one after another, not in parallel).

The structure is:

```
<Window....>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="App_Build">
            ....
            <MediaTimeline FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="Pong_Public_D_145_wav" Source="Pong-Public_D-145.wav" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button1">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="App_Build_BeginStoryboard1" Storyboard="{StaticResource App_Build}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"....>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Pong_Public_D_145_wav" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Volume="1"..../>

        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="App Start" ..../>

        ......

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[I've removed all layout properties for brevity, plus the storyboard has more animations for visuals (opacity, visibility, etc.)]

What happens is when I click the button the storyboard runs as expected every time (I see the visuals change) but the sound is sometimes played and sometimes not.

I was not able to find any "rule" to when the sound is played. Sometimes it's played on first run, sometimes not. Sometimes it's playing 10 times in a row, sometimes it's not playing for 10 times. Sometimes it's playing on every alternating run (play -> no play -> play -> no play...).

The reason for multiple runs: this is a concept for the actual application, I need to present it to the client for them to approve it. They will want to see the animation multiple times, and the sound should play every time - it's an integral part of the whole animation.

I'm really stumped here, would like to hear any suggestion, in any direction.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If you did, post an answer with the fix!

Comment: No, unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve it using storyboard. The client took it upon themselves to sync the animation with the sound. They play the sound via regular Win32 APIs and have a small framework to sync it with the animation. I haven't inspected their code deep enough so I don't know details about how they did it.